# Lean and inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, formal-proofs, type-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

[Here](https://github.com/digama0/lean-type-theory/releases) it is claimed that Lean's type theory is equiconsistent with ZFC + existence of $n$ inaccessible cardinals for every natural $n$. This is a bit worrying if you just want to work with pure ZFC: how do you know if the proof in Lean didn't use the existence of inaccessible cardinals? A first thought would be checking that the proof used didn't use `Type u` for `u` bigger than $0$, but someone told me this is not enough. Can someone offer more insight into this?

Comment: I don’t know much about Lean specifically, but I do know that the aspect of Coq which makes it equiconsistent with ZFC + infinitely many inaccessibles is a combination of the impredicative Prop universe (quantifying over all propositions gives you another proposition) and the universes.

Comment: you might also want to ask this at the new https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get an answer here